# why .data segment isnt ASLR randomized?

Tags: assembly, elf, segment, aslr

running `sysctl -a --pattern "randomize"`=`2`, so the data segemnt is supposed to be randomized also but `cat maps` always seems to randomize `vdso` `stack` and other kernal provided mappings only. These are first 2 entries of process maps file refering for `.text` and `.data`

```
cat maps
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 14569655 
00402000-00403000 rwxp 00002000 08:07 14569655
```

I halted application so i can read maps file by running it in gdb with `set disable-randomization off`.The source code i use is:

```
section .data
    name: db "k"
section .text
global _start
_start:
end:    mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

built and linked as:

```
ld sand.o -o sand
nasm -g -F DWARF -f elf64 -o sand.o sand.asm
```

another side question, I guess that `.text` cant be randomized since there is no need for it as it's read, right or wrong ?

Comment: The distance between .text and other segments is a link-time constant, that's why RIP-relative addressing works.  Non-PIE executables can only ASLR the stack.

Comment: Only position independent executabes (PIE) can have their load address randomized.  Even then, only the entire executable image can be relocated in memory, moving the `.data` and `.text` and all other loaded sections together.

Comment: @peterCordes I still can't understand why this isnt PIC when i'm not referencing any memory so can't the linker do some fixups at load time (like relocating). I know i have lots of confusion on how these things work. and how to fix above code to be PIC.

Comment: Yes, that code could be linked into a PIE executable, if you use the right option for `ld`.  That isn't the default.